# How to overlay an image inside an image with HTML, CSS

Tags: html, css, image, twitter-bootstrap

Is it possible to overlay an image and a text inside of an `<img>`? To look something similar like the image below. I'm using Bootstrap

this is how I'm trying to do it:

#### html

```
<div class="form-group">
    <img id="uploadPreview" class="photo-style">
</div>
<div class="form-group">
    <input type="file" capture="camera" accept="image/*" id="id_photo" 
           name="photo" onchange="PreviewImage();">
</div>
```

#### css

```
.photo-style{
  display: block; 
  width: 100%;
  height: 325px;
  background: lightyellow url(../img/internet-world.png);
  margin-left: auto; 
  margin-right: auto !important;
  border-radius: 4px;
}
```

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use `position` property of css

```
.parent{
position:relative;
}

.child{
position:absolute;
left:50%;
top:50%
}
```

Answer (score 1):

you Can just make a div with a p tag containing your text, then use css to position the text and give your div the right height/width and apply a background-image on the div?